# 2h 20m layover at Istanbul Airport (IST)

Tags: transit, transit-visas, bangladeshi-citizens, canadian-residents, ist

I am a Bangladesh passport holder and a Canadian permanent resident.

On my way from Dhaka Airport (DAC) to Toronto Airport (YYZ) one of my layovers will be at Istanbul Airport (IST) for 2 hour 20 minutes for a connecting flight.

Will I need any visa just to change flights at IST airport?